# Column is not being grouped exception in Scatterplot

Tags: sql, apache-calcite, omniscidb

I am trying to create a Scatter chart in OmniSci with a Y-Axis set to the following custom measure:

```
(CASE
 WHEN (footage_drilled/${Footage_Available}) > 1 THEN 1 
 ELSE  (footage_drilled/${Footage_Available})
END)
```

but the chart fails to render and throws the following exception:

```
Could not render chart
Exception: Exception occurred: org.apache.calcite.runtime. CalciteContextException: From line 2, column 56 to line 2, column 86: Exp
ression 'footage_drilled' is not being grouped
```

What would be the best way to "group by" the `footage_drilled` field so that it complys with the Scatterplot requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is you need to wrap your custom measure in an aggregate (AVG, SUM, etc) given the chart is creating a group-by query. For the scatterplot you can also visualize ungrouped data (by not adding anything as a dimension), in which case you would not need the aggregate wrapper.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that was the issue, indeed! :)